# How to do multiple queries on a mysql table with php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am new to coding PHP/MySQL/JS, so please excuse if this is a dumb question. I have a database table:

```
primary_key | main | heading | subheading | subsubheading
```

In this table, I need to return `primary_key` and I have to search through the table. Each `primary_key` has a unique combination of headings, but there are only about 100 different headings (a `subheading` can repeat under a different `heading`). How would I do something like java's `ArrayList.query(main).query(heading).query(subheading).query(subsubheading);` in PHP within a JavaScript file?

Comment: If you aren't using any kind of ORM framework for php, you need to use a pure mysql SELECT statement like this:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a SELECT statement and multiple WHERE statements. This is one of the most basic MySQL commands.